# How to get the post name (slug) from the item ID when traversing the navbar?

Tags: menus, slug

I'm working on a filter for nav menu items, such as

```
add_filter('wp_get_nav_menu_items','nav_items', 11, 3);
function nav_items($items, $menu, $args) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $slug_1 = get_post_field('post_name', $item->ID);
        $slug_2 = $item->post_name;
        // ...
    }
    return $items;
}
```

But neither `$slug_1` and `$slug_2` returns the correct slug.

What is the correct way to get the slug associated to a navbar item?

Comment: Note that the menu item is not the post being linked to, but a post of type `nav_menu_item`, it's a hidden post type used just for nav menus

Answer (score 3):

May be duplicate, but I wasn't able to find the answer. `$item->object_id` stores the actual post ID:

```
$slug = get_post_field('post_name', $item->object_id);
```